# How to launch two threads in bash shell script?

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, scp

I am trying to copy files from `machineB` and `machineC` into `machineA` as I am running my below shell script on `machineA`.

If the files is not there in `machineB` then it should be there in `machineC` for sure so I will try copying the files from `machineB` first, if it is not there in `machineB` then I will try copying the same files from `machineC`.

I am copying the files in parallel using GNU Parallel library and it is working fine. Currently I am copying two files in parallel.

Currently, I am copying the `PRIMARY_PARTITION` files in `PRIMARY` folder using GNU parallel and once that is done, then I copy the `SECONDARY_PARTITION` files in `SECONDARY` folder using same GNU parallel so it is sequential as of now w.r.t `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` folder

Below is my shell script and everything works fine -

```
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/test01/primary
export SECONDARY=/test02/secondary
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
export FILERS_LOCATION_1=${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}
export FILERS_LOCATION_2=${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(550 274 2 546 278) # this will have more file numbers
SECONDARY_PARTITION=(1643 1103 1372 1096 1369) # this will have more file numbers

export dir3=/testing/snapshot/20140103

# delete primary files first and then copy
find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_CopyInPrimary() {
  el=$1
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyInPrimary
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInPrimary ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"

# delete secondary files first and then copy
find "$SECONDARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_CopyInSecondary() {
  el=$1
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyInSecondary
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInSecondary ::: "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Is there any way I can launch two threads, one to copy files in `PRIMARY` folder using the same setup as I have above, meaning it will copy two files in parallel. And second thread to copy the files in `SECONDARY` folder using the same setup as I have above, it should also copy two files parallel simultaneously?

Meaning they should copy files in parallel both in `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` folder simultaneously not once `PRIMARY` folder is done, then copy files in `SECONDARY` folder.

Currently, once `PRIMARY` folder file is done, then only I try copying the files in `SECONDARY` folder.

In short, I just need to launch two threads one thread will run this -

```
# delete primary files first and then copy
find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_CopyInPrimary() {
  el=$1
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyInPrimary
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInPrimary ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

And second thread will run this -

```
# delete secondary files first and then copy
find "$SECONDARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_CopyInSecondary() {
  el=$1
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyInSecondary
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInSecondary ::: "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}"
```

And once all the files are copied successfully, it should echo the message, that all the files are copied. In java, I know how to launch two threads and each thread is performing certain task but not sure how in bash shell script this will work?

My main task is to copy two files in parallel using GNU parallel in `PRIMARY` folder and `SECONDARY` folder at a same time?

Is this possible to do in bash shell script?

Comment: Depending on your hard drive, you may not want to copy to two different locations simultaneously on the same drive. It means that you have to copy a little bit to one spot, and then find the other spot to write to it, and then find your first spot again.

Unless it is imperative that you have both of them writing simultaneously, I would run one after the other.

Read more [here](http://superuser.com/questions/252959/which-is-faster-copying-everything-at-once-or-one-thing-at-a-time)

Answer (score 1):

Simply launching another bash script to run in the terminal using the & operator would probably solve your needs here

Comment: @fopis: Can you provide an example if possible how this will work out with my example?